# Jquery, changing image src in a loop. Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to make a script, which will replace any uploaded image to a specfic block to another image via replacing "filename" in src to "1 + filename".

Here is a target page: http://nikita.windowspros.ru/product/night-city/

So for every woocommerce gallery image I will show a different one on hover:

```
    //no conflict for wordpress
$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

//when hover gallery item
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".woocommerce-product-gallery__image").hover(function() {

//for each img in it find filename and replace to 1+filename**
$(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").each(function() {

    var src = $(this).attr("src"); // "/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"
    var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["wp-content","uploads","2017","07","filename.jpg"]
    var file = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "filename.jpg"
    var data = file.split('.')[0];  // "filename"
    var newdata = data.replace(data, "1" + data);

    $(this).removeAttr("srcset");
    $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/" + newdata + ".jpg");
  });
});
});
```

It would also be great to find and change 2017/07 folder to whatever the file is in

Please help StackOverflow, you are my only hope :(

Comment: So what its the problem? and use `var src = $(this).attr("src");`

Comment: Not sure yet, do I have syntax errors?

Comment: I added $(this) as you proposed. 

For some reason it ads not "1" to file name, but it does 11, 111, 1111 depending on how many times you hover. also it doesn't return to original state when I stop hovering

Comment: Don't do this: `$ = jQuery.noConflict(); $(document).ready(function(){` - instead, just do this: `jQuery(function($) {`...

Comment: Sam, _ask your browser_ if you have syntax errors.  Try the code.  Does it report errors in the console? If so, try to fix them.  And *yes*, you have some potential problems.  For example, what if the original image is not a `jpg`? You force them all to be `jpg`, regardless of how they started life.  I see no reason / value to doing the `file.split(.)` - just keep the full file name, and prepend the 1, that way you can support any type of image.

Comment: Both comments are helpful, but it's already working and gives me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Made it! woo hoo.

```
jQuery(function($) {
        //$(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").removeAttr("srcset");
        //MOBILE
        $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").bind("touchstart", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src"); // "/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"
            var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["wp-content","uploads","2017","07","filename.jpg"]
            var year = tarr[tarr.length-3];
            var month = tarr[tarr.length-2];
            var data = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "filename.jpg"
            var newdata = data.replace(data, "1" + data);
            $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            $(this).attr("srcset","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            });
                });
        $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").bind("touchend", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src"); // "/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"
            var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["wp-content","uploads","2017","07","filename.jpg"]
            var year = tarr[tarr.length-3];
            var month = tarr[tarr.length-2];
            var data = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "filename.jpg"
            var newdata = data.slice(1,data.length);
            $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            $(this).attr("srcset","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            }); 
                });
        //PC        
        $( ".woocommerce-product-gallery__image").hover(
            function() {
            $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src"); // "/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"
            var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["wp-content","uploads","2017","07","filename.jpg"]
            var year = tarr[tarr.length-3];
            var month = tarr[tarr.length-2];
            var data = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "filename.jpg"
            var newdata = data.replace(data, "1" + data);
            $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            $(this).attr("srcset","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            });
        },
            function() {
            $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr("src"); // "/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/filename.jpg"
            var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["wp-content","uploads","2017","07","filename.jpg"]
            var year = tarr[tarr.length-3];
            var month = tarr[tarr.length-2];
            var data = tarr[tarr.length-1]; // "filename.jpg"
            var newdata = data.slice(1,data.length);
            $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            $(this).attr("srcset","/wp-content/uploads/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + newdata);
            }); 
        });
                $(".woocommerce-product-gallery__image > a > img").on("click", function() {
        return false;
        });
    });
```